# Installed Xubuntu desktop on Ubuntu 12.04 server and now can't connect via SSH

Tags: ssh, xubuntu, firewall, remote

I have a ubuntu 12.04 server that I could connect to fine using ssh over the internet. I installed the xubuntu desktop on it, didn't change any settings, then suddenly ssh stopped working.

I can connect locally using "ssh localhost"

I can't connect if I type "ssh (public ip address)"

I can connect using a different computer on the same local network like "ssh 192.168.2.5"

I double checked to make sure the ports are forwarded correctly, when I use a online port checking tool I can confirm that port 22 is open.

I confirmed that the firewall is off using "sudo ufw disable"

Any other ideas what it might be? Should I just reinstall ubuntu server or is there a obvious thing I'm missing? Any help appreciated or just send me in the right direction, I don't mind reading to figure it out but I don't know where to start, thanks!!!

Comment: Please try to run ssh server in debug mode, attempt a connection and edit your question to include the ssh servers debug output. Also, please add the output of the client when using the verbose output option.

Comment: This exact thing has happened to me on Ubuntu 20.04. My guess is that by making it a 'desktop' installation it disables a bunch of this stuff by default.

Answer (score 1):

This probably not a ssh config problem if it is working on your local network.

Are you sure ssh is not filtered by a local firewall when you do the check from the outside ? You can try: `telnet portquiz.positon.org 22` to test that.

What error do you get? ssh timeout? If it is a timeout this is probably a firewall issue.

You can also check `/var/log/auth.log` on your ssh server.

Test a `telnet yourserverpublicip 22` from outside, and check the output of `netstat -anp` or `tcpdump -ni any port 22`

One more idea: some local NAT firewalls do not support NAT loopback so that the connection from outside on your public ip will work, but not from inside your NATed network.